# array_keys issue with getting the Key of 1st level Array providing the Value of the 2nd level array

Tags: php, arrays, key

I'm trying to get the Key of 1st level Array providing the value of the 2nd level array but it's not working.
What am I doing wrong here? Thanks very much.

```
$linksUrls = array(
    'index'=>array('ar'=>'inicio','en'=>'home'),
    'portfolio'=>array('ar'=>'portfolio-de-fotografia/casas','en'=>'photography-portfolio/homes'),
    'contacto'=>array('ar'=>'contacto','en'=>'contact')
            );

/* This one will not work */
print_r(array_keys($linksUrls,'contact'));

/* This one will */
function search($arr, $srch){ 
                         foreach($arr as $key => $val){ 
                               foreach($val as $k => $v){
                                     if ($v == $srch){ echo $key; } 
                                } 
                             } 
} 

search($linksUrls, "contact");
```

Thanks to Kyle...

Answer (score 0):

Or you did a typo and meant

`print_r(array_keys($linksUrls,'contacto'))` instead of  `print_r(array_keys($linksUrls,'contact'))`, or you actually want to do a deep search since the array_keys function doesn't look to the arrays inside the array you passed as parameter (recursive search).

If you want to do a recursive search take a look over here: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php#105890

Comment: I do want to do a deep search... I'll take a look at this article . ..thanks very much Luis...

Answer (score 0):

the function array_keys searches only one level deep. Since you're working with a 2-level array, you will need function for searching all the nested arrays. Check out the PHP.net page for several options, however from experience I say this [one works](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php#84659) fine!

Answer (score 0):

Heres a function for ya....

It lets you input the array, and the value you wanna find the key of...

```
function search($arr, $srch){
   foreach($arr as $key => $val){
   if(is_array($val))search($val, $srch);
   if($val==$srch){echo $key;}
   }
}
```

Then just use it like so...

```
 search($linksUrls, "contact");
```

Comment: It's close to be to what I'm looking for ... this one output "en" .. but I need to output "contacto" .. or if I use the value "home" I need to output "index"... I don't know if it's clear enough... As it is a 2-level array I'll try to twist a little bit this function and see if I can get some result .. Thanks very much Kyle...  :)

Comment: I rephrase my question above. Sorry I didn't explain myself very well... Thanks...

Comment: what about this one Kyle ?

`function search($arr, $srch){
 foreach($arr as $key => $val){
  foreach($val as $k => $v){
   if ($v == $srch){
    echo $key;
   }
  }
 }
}

search($linksUrls, "contact");`

Answer (score 0):

```
/* This one will not work */
print_r(array_keys($linksUrls,'contact'));

/* This one will */
function search($arr, $srch){ 
                     foreach($arr as $key => $val){ 
                           foreach($val as $k => $v){
                                 if ($v == $srch){ echo $key; } 
                            } 
                         } 
} 

search($linksUrls, "contact");
```